# Is $R = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x - y \in \mathbb{N}\}$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

Note: I am also trying to answer my own question, but I am not sure if it is correct, please correct it, if it's wrong. Thanks :)

I have an exercise where I have to say if a relation $R$ is or not an *equivalence relation*, and this are the 2 examples:

1. $R = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x - y \in \mathbb{N}\}$
2. $R = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x - y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

My answer is **no** for first case, because $R$ is not symmetric, but reflexive. Suppose $x = 1.313$ and $y = 0.313$, then it's not *symmetric*, since $x - y \in \mathbb{N}$, but $y - x \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

For second case, my answer is **yes**, since it's *symmetric* and transitive, and of course also reflexive. The following is my proof:

1. ***Reflexive***:

   Suppose $x = 3.14$, then $x - x = 0 \in \mathbb{Q}$
2. ***Symmetric***:

   Suppose $x = 1.5$ and $y = 2.0$.

   Then $x - y = -0.5 = -\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $y - x = 0.5 = \frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$

   So $R$ is *symmetric*.
3. ***Transitive***:

   Suppose $x = 1.5$, $y = 2.0$ and $z = 3.5$.

   We have that:

   $x - y = -0.5 \in \mathbb{Q}$

   $y - z = -1.5 \in \mathbb{Q}$

   $x - z = -2.0 \in \mathbb{Q}$

   So $R$ is transitive.

Since $R$ is *reflexive*, *symmetric* and *transitive*, we can say that $R$ is an *equivalence relation* (for the second case).

Comment: Downvoting means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear of not useful". That the OP tried to answer it is clear: the proof is below. I do not think that this question is not useful either. To the downvoters: could you please leave a comment?

Comment: I suspect the reason your question was down voted is that you did not include your work in the statement of your question.  If you had included your answer as part of your question, I suspect the down votes would not have appeared.  There is an expectation on this site that you include your own thoughts on the problem and any work you have done on it in the question itself rather than the answers.  The people who voted down your question may not have realized that you did show your work unless they also read your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some misunderstanding on how proofs work. To show that a relation is reflexive, you must show that $(x, x) \in R$ for ALL $x$, not just one. To show it is not reflexive, you simply demonstrate some $x$ for which it is not reflexive. Your second proof is invalid because **it does not show that it always true, it only gives an example**. Consider the following relation defined on the numbers $0$ and $1$:

$$ D = \{(0, 0), (0, 1) \} $$

Is $D$ reflexive? **No**. Even though $(0,0) \in D$, we have $(1, 1) \not\in D$. One example does not prove a statement (although a counterexample will disprove a statement).

Here is another statement: $x \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. You cannot prove this statement by exhibiting one example or even infinitely many, since it is false for any negative $x$.

So let's try and prove your statement correctly.

1. Reflexive. Since $x-x=0\in \mathbb Q$, we know $xRx$ so $R$ is reflexive.
2. Symmetric. We have to prove that if $x R y$, then $y R x$. This means that if $x - y \in \mathbb Q$, then $y-x \in \mathbb Q$. Let $x - y = \frac{r}{s}$, where $r$ and $s$ are integers (we can do this since $x-y\in \mathbb Q$, so it is the quotient of integers). Now $y-x = \frac{-r}{s}$, which is the quotient of integers, and so $y-x\in\mathbb Q$. Therefore the relation is symmetric. (Basically, you want to show that if $q\in\mathbb Q$ then $-q \in\mathbb Q$.)
3. Transitive. We need to show if $x - y \in \mathbb Q$ and $y - z \in \mathbb Q$, then $x - z \in \mathbb Q$. Note that the rationals are **closed under addition**, so $(x-y) + (y-z) = x - z \in \mathbb Q$. Therefore the relationship is transitive.

Comment: @Rinzler: Just one minor observation: do you see what will happen if we choose $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$? (this may be an exercise in you exam :D)

Comment: no. it means the set of all irrationals. it's an alternative notation for $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q.$

Comment: @Rinzler: for $\mathbb Z$ is an equivalence relation (proof is same as for $\mathbb Q$). for $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q,$ it's not. can't be reflexive as $0 \notin \mathbb R - \mathbb Q.$